# how to add models state error and show in view page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

if user is not fill all the text box and click submit button ,then how to add models state error and show in view page (or) how to show this error(all fields are mandatory) in view page.i have not good knowledge in  asp.net, I recently learn this,so please help me.it should be very hard for me..thanking you

```html
 

    @using StackApplication.Modelsl;



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Register Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div id="title">
            <font color="blue">  <b> <h1>STaCK</h1> </b> </font>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <a href="" style="color:white;
                padding:10px;">Log in</a>
            <a href="" style="color:white;">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="float:left;width:100%;padding:left:10px;top:5px;">
        <center>
            <b><i>  <h2><font color="#010100">Register Form</font></h2> </i></b>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <center>
            @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>Username</h3></th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserAccount.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Username", @id = "txtUsername", @required="required" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>Email id</h3></th>
                        <td>

                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserAccount.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email", @id = "txtEmail", @required = "required" })

                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>Password</h3></th>
                        <td>
                           
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserAccount.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password", @id = "txtPassword", @required = "required", @type="password" })          
                            
                             
                       </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="register" value="REGISTER" id="buttondesign" />
                <br />
                <br />
            }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
public class StackProvider
{
    public object ModelState { get; private set; }

    public string CreateUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount)
    {
        try
        {
            StackRepository repository = new StackRepository();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAccount.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAccount.Password)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAccount.UserName))
            {
                return "All fields are mandatory.";
            }

            int count = repository.GetUseraccountByEmail(userAccount.Email);

            if (count > 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username already exist");
                return "Username already exist";
            }

            repository.CreateUserAccount(userAccount);

            return "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Adding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation)

Answer (score 0):

If i do custom validation on properties or model ,I do like this,I watched your problem ,so try this may help you for submit form and...

=>At the end of the execution **ModelState Object** will contain all the errors which are added for failed validation. Also the **modelState object will contain the error message.**

=>As we are **checking the value of IsValid property and it gets set to false**, so we are redirecting the user to the register view again to fill up the fields.

```
           public ActionResult Register()
           {
             return View();


        }
      [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Register( Register registermodel)
        //Here we are checking wether input field are null or Empty

    //if fields are Null/Empty ,we are  adding error in ModelState object against those properties
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registermodel.UserName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName","UserName is required");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registermodel.email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("email ", "email is required");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registermodel.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password ", "Password is required");
        }



        //Here,if All the validation are passed then redirect to index page.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        //if we got this far,something failed,redisplay form
        return View(registermodel);
    }
```